# How can you set up Spring Loaded with Kotlin, Gradle, and a web framework?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, kotlin, dropwizard, spring-loaded

I'm new to the JVM and interested in trying Kotlin for RESTful web development. Hot reloading is a dev feature I'm used to from dynamic scripting languages like Python, Ruby, and JavaScript.

Play, Dropwizard, and Spring Boot all seem appealing. I'd be willing to use any of the above, but I've been unable to get a simple "save file, reload webpage" workflow set up with any of the above.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: jrebel is working with kotlin as I known https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified FOSS – JRebel costs $475/yr/dev https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/pricing/

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, have you checked [Spring Boot DevTools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools)? The whole point of devtools is to do that.

Comment: Yes, I tried Spring Boot DevTools to no avail =/

Comment: Oh, and Spring Loaded crashed – perhaps I should file a report / ask a separate SO question about that...

Answer (score -3):

Check out this sbt plugin:
https://github.com/pfn/kotlin-plugin

Haven't tried it myself, maybe this is what you are looking for.